# How can I make ESLint enforce imports to either be all on separate lines or all on a single line?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I use ESLint to lint TypeScript. I would like to configure ESLint such that it enforces imports to either be all on separate lines or all on a single line.

Not okay:

```
import {
    a, b,
    c,
    d
} from "letters";
```

Okay:

```
import { a, b, c, d } from "letters";
```

Okay:

```
import {
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
} from "letters";
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: There is a rule for that for objects called [object-property-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline) with the configuration `["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true }]`. However I'm not sure will it work for imports and I was unable to find a rule like that for them.

Comment: Thanks @5ar, but that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: For the always vertical part you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-eslint-vertical-import or https://github.com/eydrian/tslint-vertical-import

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### I found a solution for this issue!

I spent 4-5 hours yesterday on this topic.

Please use https://github.com/SeinopSys/eslint-plugin-import-newlines (plugin to eslint).

It only takes a few steps to meet your requirements:

1. Install plugin `npm install eslint-plugin-import-newlines --save-dev`
2. Add `import-newlines` to the plugin section of your `.eslintrc` configuration file as below.

```
{
    plugins: ['import-newlines'],
}
```

3. Add `import-newlines/enforce` to the rules section of your `.eslintrc` configuration file as below (default rule).

```
{
    rules: {
        'import-newlines/enforce': 'error',
    }
}
```

or (my rule)

```
{
    rules: {
        'import-newlines/enforce': ['error', { items: 40, 'max-len': 120 }],
    }
}
```

My rule works as described below:

1. For `import` with length up to 120 characters in one line (counted internally), the import will be forced in one line.
2. For `import` with length more than 120 characters in one line (counted internally), the import will be forced on multiple lines (each imported item will be on a separate line)

### Good luck and have fun!

Comment: nice one, do you know any similar but for props?

Comment: @FerToasted yes, I know :) See my rule: `{ rules: { 'object-property-newline': ['error', { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }] } }`